# How to purposely have the "Non Pnp Monitor" available on the resolution screen

Tags: display, resolution

I bought a TV to use it as a single monitor for my PC:

(http://www.walmart.com.mx/TV-y-Video/Pantallas/30-a-39-Pulgadas/TV-Kodak_29-Pulgadas-720p-HD-LED_00081753701122)

In the box it said it was 1366x768, and indeed, when I connect it to my computer, in the "screen" dropdown menu in the resolution screen, I'm able to see 1 option that says "SKYWORTH TV", with 1366x768 being the max resolution.

While connecting and disconnecting some cables, I accidentally unplugged the TV from the powersource while it was still being used.

When I plug it back in, instead of having the "SKYWORTH TV" single option, I instead have a "Non Pnp Monitor" option, and to my surprise it can go all the way up to something around 2050x1000.

When I turn off the monitor and come back the next day, I'm back with the "SKYWORTH TV" option and with the maximum resolution being 1366x768.

I've seen alot of posts about the "non pnp monitor" issue, but is there a way to purposely have the resolution up to something around 2050x1000 by having it show the "non pnp monitor" option, I now know its posible to have a higher resolution in this screen, so ti would be great to keep it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see the problem, or question... The Non PNP monitor entry you got was because the identity and capabilities did not transfer properly from the TV to the computer. HDMI should always be connected with both devices powered off, and then the display powered on first, followed by the device so that proper handshaking occurs (many devices support "hot" connecting, your TV obviously does not properly handle this). The Non PNP resolutions displayed are all that are possible by your video card because it can't determine the displays capabilities but it expects you to know. Going outside of your displays capabilities (only 1366*768 @ xxhz) could actually damage your TV.

If you understand this and wish to try anyway, just change the driver for the display in properties to Non Plug and Play or Default monitor. Do not change your graphics card settings. Note that this may not work, or may not "stick" since Windows and your graphics card think they are smarter than you and will probably automatically update the settings when handshaking of identity and capabilities occur.